# Biblatex: Change order of fields (note+pages) for inproceedings/incollection

Tags: macros, biblatex, bibliographies

I'm using the following to change the order of note and pages fields for @article.

```
\renewbibmacro{note+pages}{%
  \printfield{pages}%
  \setunit*{\space}%
  \printfield{note}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \newunit
}
```

I struggle to find something similar for @inproceedings. I guess the note+pages marco is not used there. How can I find out which macro is used instead?

Comment: With `@inproceedings` the `note` field is printed with a simple `\printfield{note}%` in the driver and then later the pages come with `usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%`. You could simply use the `addendum` field which is printed later. Or you could re-order the driver (maybe even with `xpatch`), or you could save the `note` field, then clear it and print the saved field later.

Answer (score 1):

Following moewe's suggestion, I use `xpatch`'s `\xpatchbibdriver` to remove the `\printfield{note}` and then to add it before the `\usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}`:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{moraux,
  author       = {Moraux, Paul},
  editor       = {Lloyd, G. E. R. and Owen, G. E. L.},
  title        = {Le \emph{De Anima} dans la tradition gr{\`e}cque},
  date         = 1979,
  booktitle    = {Aristotle on Mind and the Senses},
  subtitle     = {Quelques aspects de l'interpretation du trait{\'e}, de
                  Theophraste {\`a} Themistius},
  booktitleaddon= {Proceedings of the Seventh Symposium Aristotelicum},
  eventdate    = 1975,
  publisher    = cup,
  location     = {Cambridge},
  pages        = {281-324},
  keywords     = {secondary},
  langid       = {french},
  indexsorttitle= {De Anima dans la tradition grecque},
  indextitle   = {\emph{De Anima} dans la tradition gr{\`e}cque, Le},
  shorttitle   = {\emph{De Anima} dans la tradition gr{\`e}cque},
  annotation   = {This is a typical \texttt{inproceedings} entry. Note the
                  \texttt{booksubtitle}, \texttt{shorttitle},
                  \texttt{indextitle}, and \texttt{indexsorttitle} fields. Also
                  note the \texttt{eventdate} field.},
  note = {This is a note},
  url = {https://fake.url}
}

@inproceedings{salam,
  author       = {Salam, Abdus},
  editor       = {Svartholm, Nils},
  title        = {Weak and Electromagnetic Interactions},
  date         = 1968,
  booktitle    = {Elementary particle theory},
  booksubtitle = {Relativistic groups and analyticity},
  booktitleaddon= {Proceedings of the {Eighth Nobel Symposium}},
  eventdate    = {1968-05-19/1968-05-25},
  venue        = {Aspen{\"a}sgarden, Lerum},
  publisher    = {Almquist \& Wiksell},
  location     = {Stockholm},
  pages        = {367-377},
  note = {This is a note},
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibdriver{inproceedings}{\printfield{note}}{}{}{}
\xpatchbibdriver{inproceedings}{\usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}}{\printfield{note}\newunit\newblock\usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}}{}{}
\begin{document}
\cites{moraux,salam}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

> [image: mwe]